# LWC - Multiple createRecord calls

Tags: lightning-web-components, promises

I have a Lightning Datatable containing possible Opportunities.  The user can select which records they wish to create Opportunities and click a button (handleContinue below) which creates new Opportunity.  I loop through the selected rows and call createRecord one at a time.

This code works just fine, but I'm wondering if it possible to wrap those createRecord calls in a "parent" promise? We want to show a Lightning Spinner while those Opportunities are being created, then show a result of the entire process (successes, failures)

I'm still pretty new at this, so any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
handleContinue() {

  var selectedBeneficiaries = this.template
      .querySelector("lightning-datatable")
      .getSelectedRows();

  selectedBeneficiaries.forEach(function(bene) {

    const fields = {};
    fields[OPP_CLOSE_DATE_FIELD.fieldApiName] = '2020-03-31';
    fields[OPP_NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName] = bene.AccountName + ' Opportunity';
    fields[OPP_STAGE_FIELD.fieldApiName] = "New";

    const recordInput = { apiName: OPP_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields };
    createRecord(recordInput)
      .then(success => {
        bene.success = true;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        bene.success = false;
      });
});
```

Comment: Why not use apex and do a bulk insert? It would be faster than individual inserts

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Thanks for reply - I did start down that route, but read using recordAPI is the recommended route to take?

Comment: For single records yeh... I won't recommend for bulk as apex gives you transaction control, roll back, and more

Comment: Awesome, thanks that makes a lot of sense.  I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try do to this in bulk:

```
Promise.all(
selectedBeneficiaries.map(bene => {
    const fields = {};
    fields[OPP_CLOSE_DATE_FIELD.fieldApiName] = '2020-03-31';
    fields[OPP_NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName] = bene.AccountName + ' Opportunity';
    fields[OPP_STAGE_FIELD.fieldApiName] = "New";
    const recordInput = { apiName: OPP_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields };
    return createRecord(recordInput);
})).then(results => {
    // ... //
}).catch(error => {
    // ... //
});
```

This would be okay for a relatively small number of records, but Apex would have better performance for large lists.

Comment: Thanks for providing the JS promise way of doing it.  This should work for my purposes as I'm only creating 5 opportunities max.  I did code the Apex method as well, but it seems like this gives you more control over the events (success, failures, etc.)

Comment: @MikeG. Yes, I feel like it's always good to have different options available. Apex would be overkill for small updates, but necessary for large updates. Having multiple tools available makes a developer more flexible.

Comment: @sfdcfox What if I want to to all or nothing? Would there be a mechanism to achieve that using `createRecord()` without making subsequent calls to the database to erase any successful inserts?

Comment: @Arthlete Nope, unfortunately not. That would be a limitation of this design. If you need that level of transaction control, use Apex.